# Identify periods of silence

Tags: silence

I have some audios that contain short spaces of silence with different periods of time.

The [audio sample](https://wolfr.am/mSeG89Up) is this.

**Is there a way by which Audition software can do the following sequence below?**

Identify periods of silence and convert all these periods to 1 second